# How to split lstlistings with large code into two frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings, minipage

I am designing a slide of Python language and I want to show the execution of algorithm step-by-step (line by line) refreshing the state of variables and simulating the output in any console (simulating a debugger tool).

My problem is that i was faced with a large algorithm that I should be split in two or more frames of beamer. My slide highlight the current line executed. Thus, I have to set in latex the number of frame and the number of line that be colorized.

When the `lstlisting` is too large (a lot of lines), I have to:

1. reinsert `lstlisting` in a new frame (called "frame 2");
2. set the range of remaining lines of same code that I want to show;
3. set a line counter of code starting at a first line after the last line of a previous frame;
4. insert a lot of commands which highlight lines of a snippet of code reinserted in a frame 2;

This way is too much expensive and make me to (roughly) copy a full code of previous frame.
There's a way that I implement `lstlisting` for a only frame and LaTex split automatically the code among frames?

Below, my latex code (`lstinputlisting` is most important part).

Thanks so much in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% A CONFIG FILE
\input{config.tex}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{rgb}{0.07, 0.04, 0.56}
\definecolor{ufop-verde}{RGB}{57, 155, 60}

% ALL PACKAGES
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{float}        
\usepackage{pgf, pgffor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\newcommand{\numeroaula}{01234}


%% THIS SEQUENCE OS LINES ENABLE THE HIGHLIGHT OF SOURCE CODE INSIDE LSTLISTNGS
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \btIfInRange{number}{range list}{TRUE}{FALSE}
%
% Test in int number <number> is element of a (comma separated) list of ranges
% (such as: {1,3-5,7,10-12,14}) and processes <TRUE> or <FALSE> respectively

\newcount\bt@rangea
\newcount\bt@rangeb

\newcommand\btIfInRange[2]{%
    \global\let\bt@inrange\@secondoftwo%
    \edef\bt@rangelist{#2}%
    \foreach \range in \bt@rangelist {%
        \afterassignment\bt@getrangeb%
        \bt@rangea=0\range\relax%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{ ( #1 >= \bt@rangea) && (#1 <= \bt@rangeb) }%
        \ifnum\result=1\relax%
            \breakforeach%
            \global\let\bt@inrange\@firstoftwo%
        \fi%
    }%
    \bt@inrange%
}
\newcommand\bt@getrangeb{%
    \@ifnextchar\relax%
        {\bt@rangeb=\bt@rangea}%
        {\@getrangeb}%
}
\def\@getrangeb-#1\relax{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \bt@rangeb=100000%   \maxdimen is too large for pgfmath
    \else%
        \bt@rangeb=#1\relax%
    \fi%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \btLstHL<overlay spec>{range list}
%
% TODO BUG: \btLstHL commands can not yet be accumulated if more than one overlay spec match.
% 
\newcommand<>{\btLstHL}[1]{%
  \only#2{\btIfInRange{\value{lstnumber}}{#1}{\color{orange!25}\def\lst@linebgrdcmd{\color@block}}{\def\lst@linebgrdcmd####1####2####3{}}}%
}%
\makeatother
%% THES SEQUENCE ABOVE ENABLE THE HIGHLIGHT OF SOURCE CODE INSIDE LSTLISTNGS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\batchmode

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}
\usepackage{epsfig,bbm,calc,color,ifthen,capt-of}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{senac}

%-------------------------Titulo/Autores/Orientador------------------------------------------------
\title[Comando de decisão IF]{\small{BCC 701 - Programação de Computadores I}\\\LARGE{\textbf{Comando de decisão IF}}}
\date{\dataPT  -  Aula \numeroaula}
\author[DECOM]{Universidade Federal de Ouro Preto - UFOP\\Departamento de Computação - DECOM\\Material Didático Unificado\\\url{www.decom.ufop.br/bcc701}}

%-------------------------Logo na parte de baixo do slide------------------------------------------
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.0cm]{ufop-logo}{ufop-logo.pdf}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{ufop-logo}\hspace*{0.5cm}}

%-------------------------Este código faz o menuzinho bacana na parte superior do slide------------
\iffalse
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\fi
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

%---Gerador de Sumário---------------------------------------------------------
\frame{\titlepage}
\section[]{}
\begin{frame}{Sumário}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---Fim do Sumário------------------------------------------------------------

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Exemplo (passo a passo)}
\begingroup

    %% THE MOST IMPORTANTE CODE IS BELOW.           <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %% THE MOST IMPORTANTE CODE IS BELOW.           <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %% THE MOST IMPORTANTE CODE IS BELOW.           <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %% THE MOST IMPORTANTE CODE IS BELOW.           <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

%% FRAME 1
 \begin{frame}[fragile]{Exemplo (passo-a-passo)}
\vbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        %\lstinputlisting[language=Python, frame=single, linebackgroundcolor={%
        \lstinputlisting[language=Python, firstline=1, lastline=15, firstnumber=1, linebackgroundcolor={% %% HERE I SET MAX OF LINES VISIBLE IN FRAME 1 AND A FIRST NUMBER IN A COLUMN OS LINE COUNTERS
    \btLstHL<1>{1}% on slide 1, highlight lines 1-3
    \btLstHL<2>{2}% on slide 2, highlight lines 6 and 9
    \btLstHL<3,4,5>{4}% on slide 3,4,5, highlight line 4
    \btLstHL<6>{5}}% on slide 6, highlight line 5
  }]{bhaskara.py} %% THIS IS THE PYTHON CODE.
enter code here


% IF THIS PYTHON CODE IS LARGE, I HAVE TO CREATE A NEW FRAME COPYING 
% ALL LATEX CODE POSTED HERE, SET THE LINE WHERE I WANNA START PYTHON CODE 
% AND RECREATE A LIST OF \btLstHL TAGS ABOVE INSERTING THE CORRECT LINES 
% OF A SNIPPET OF CODE

\end{minipage}

    %% THE MOST IMPORTANTE CODE IS ABOVE. %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THE MOST IMPORTANTE SNIPPET IS ABOVE


    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{minipage}[b][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        \vspace{0.4in}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}

\end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
}

\end{frame}
%% END OF FRAME 1

\endgroup


\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a whole bunch of stuff in your code that is not needed for this issue (only around the end do we see `THE MOST IMPORTANT CODE IS BELOW`). You can really trim down the example to be *minimal* (and *working*) yet still representative. And we don't even have `bhaskara.py`. How about reading this: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Answer (score 4):

So what you want to do is to highlight step-by-step all lines of a code on beamer slides, and "scroll" the code according to what is your current line. Here is a very simple solution that solves this specific problem (but is not very flexible).

The idea is to have a command `\mylisting` that takes four arguments:

- the slide number
- the start and end line of the code to be displayed
- the line number to be highlighted

The command then inserts a `\lstinputlisting` inside an `\only` with the appropriate arguments. You then simply need to put `\mylisting` in your `frame` as many times as you have lines to highlight.

At the start of the `frame`, you just need to redefine the commands `\mycode` and `\mycolor` to have the code to be includecd and the color for highlighting. Thus, you can use this in different frames to display different codes (if needed).

For this example, I took a sample Python code from [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/date-and-time-script/).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\lstset{language=Python, numbers=left, xleftmargin=2em}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.py}
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print
print "Current date and time using str method of datetime object:"
print str(now)

print
print "Current date and time using instance attributes:"
print "Current year: %d" % now.year
print "Current month: %d" % now.month
print "Current day: %d" % now.day
print "Current hour: %d" % now.hour
print "Current minute: %d" % now.minute
print "Current second: %d" % now.second
print "Current microsecond: %d" % now.microsecond

print
print "Current date and time using strftime:"
print now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
\end{filecontents*}

\def\mycode{}
\def\mycolor\color{green}
\def\mylisting<#1>#2#3#4{\only<#1>{\lstinputlisting[firstline=#2, lastline=#3, firstnumber=#2, linebackgroundcolor={\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=#4\mycolor\fi}]{\mycode}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \renewcommand{\mycode}{\jobname.py}
    \renewcommand{\mycolor}{\color{yellow!30!white}}
    \mylisting<1>{1}{15}{1}
    \mylisting<2>{1}{15}{3}
    \mylisting<3>{1}{15}{6}
    \mylisting<4>{5}{20}{10}
    \mylisting<5>{5}{20}{11}
    \mylisting<6>{5}{20}{12}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]